# Why are "Copy link to highlight" links not implemented in Firefox yet?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

The [Copy link to highlight](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10256233?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) Google Chrome feature generates links that look like this:

[https://example.com/#:~:text=Example](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=Example)

so that when a user clicks on the link above, the page opens, scrolls forward if necessary, and then highlights the text "Example". These generated links also work in Microsoft Edge 95, but not in Firefox 94.

Where can I find information on why this feature is not yet implemented in Firefox?

Nothing shows up when searching for "Copy link to highlight" on [ideas@mozilla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211119115132/https://mozilla.crowdicity.com/), nor on [Firefox's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org)

Comment: A [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1753933) and [idea](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/support-text-fragments/idi-p/21797) for Firefox have been opened, also one [for Brave](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/22906). Vote and comment there! ⬆️ Canonical links are https://web.dev/text-fragments/, the [spec](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/), the [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment) and the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Text_fragments) entries.

Answer (score 6):

> Why was this feature not implemented in Firefox?

That is a question that Firefox's developers will answer better than any of us (unless one of them is a member here).

Before being a part of a feature of Chrome browser, it was an extension of  the browser as stated [here](https://www.theverge.com/2021/4/17/22389519/google-feature-chrome-90-highlighted-links)

> First launched as a browser extension called **Link to Text Fragment** last year, Google has now added the feature within Chrome itself.

[Link to Text Fragment](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/link-to-text-fragment) was introduced last year (2020) by Google. I even gave [an answer](https://www.theverge.com/2021/4/17/22389519/google-feature-chrome-90-highlighted-links) mentioning it. It's open source and a version exists for Firefox (I know you didn't ask for it).

Comment: A better answer is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/kx7mox/when_is_firefox_getting_scroll_to_text_fragment/ specifically it links to what Firefox dev's think here: https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/194 - in short, they are waiting, but the feature might make it to Firefox eventually.